"There is more TO life than sitting in a library." VS "There is more IN life than ...."
I often hear the following usage:

"There is more to life than sitting in a library reading books." The gift of love (see:39:40-39:50)

However, I wonder, if I simply said:

"There is more in life than ....."

would the sentence lose being idiomatic?

I disagree. Sitting in a library reading books sounds pretty good to me!

This use of preposition to is attributive.  The prepositional phrase complements the preceding noun and attributes that noun to the object of the preposition.

This is the key to the door.
Do you know the solution to the riddle?
Where is the lid to this pot?

There is a close relationship of some kind between key and door, solution and riddle, lid and pot. The pair are integral.

There is more to life than memes.

more has its own own complement phrase introduced by than.
There are things essential to life other than memes or in addition to memes.  In practical terms, "memes" are being presented as non-essential or at least relatively unimportant.
And "life" there is not simply biological existence but is understood to mean something beyond the cellular level, something that makes it distinctly human.
The preposition in doesn't express a sense of essentialness as strongly as to does.  We may encounter many things in life, but they may not be essential to life, life as lived by human beings.
This construction is so common that to use "in" here instead of "to"  would sound slightly "wrong", something one might expect to hear from a non-native speaker who is still learning. One would know what the speaker was trying to say.

"to" is the idiomatic choice.  The idiom is "more to {something}".  Using a different preposition is allowed, you are just not following the usual expression.  That might be a good idea, it is a matter for you to decide.
When using other words, particularly if you use "more {something}" other prepositions may be preferred: "There is more life under the sea than on land."

I think you mean prepositions, not pronouns?
